# Will the following use of strdup() cause a memory leak in C ?

Tags: string, memory-management, concatenation, strcat, strdup

char* XX (char* str) 
      {
        // CONCAT an existing string with str , and return to user
      }

And i call this program by:

`XX ( strdup("CHCHCH") );`

Will this cause a leak while not releasing what `strdup()` generates ?

It's unlikely that free the result of `XX()`  will do the job.

(Please let me know both in C and C++ , thanks !)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the XX function free()'s the argument passed in, yes this will cause a memory leak in both C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Something has to `free` the result of `strdup`.

You could consider using [Boehm's garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) and use `GC_strdup` & `GC_malloc` instead of `strdup` & `malloc`; then you don't need to bother about calling `free`

Answer (score 1):

Yes this will leak. `strdup`'s results must be freed.

For C++, on the other hand, I recommend using `std::string` rather than `char*`:

```
std::string XX( std::string const & in )
{
   return in + std::string( "Something to append" );
}
```

This is a quick-and dirty way to implement what you're talking about, but it is very readable.  You can obtain some speed improvement by passing in a mutable reference to a string for output, but unless this is in a very tight loop, there is little reason to do so, as it would likely add increased complication without booting performance significantly.